# Write a django Alluth adapter that checks if a value i unique

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Im trying to check if a value for `pid` is uniqe but i cant manage to make alluth adapter to find the pid field. Any tips? Nothin happend, but if i change pid value to `email` the code works on the email field. I cant get the pid field to work whit this function. Maybe im referencing it in a wrong way and the filed does not belong to the default account adaptet-

```
class PidMaxAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

def clean_pid(self, pid, user):
    user.profile.pid = pid
    if len(pid) > 9:
        raise ValidationError('Please enter a username value\
                                  less than the current one')
     
    # For other default validations.
    return DefaultAccountAdapter.clean_pid(self, pid)
```

Comment: Have you made the `pid` field on your profile model unique?

Comment: Hi yeas the field is made unique.But when i try register a new user that already has a accout form  validationerror send the user to a django standard error webpage. I want the Validationerror to accour in the signup form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom signup form and do your validation in there.

Here's an example where I have a setting to disable recaptcha

```
from django import forms
from django.conf import settings

from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm as BaseSignupForm
from captcha.fields import ReCaptchaField

from .widgets import RefreshingCaptchaV3


class SignupForm(BaseSignupForm):
    """ Our signup form to integrate captcha """

    captcha = ReCaptchaField(
        label='',
        widget=RefreshingCaptchaV3()
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if settings.DISABLE_RECAPTCHA:
            del self.fields['captcha']
```

You can get allauth to use your custom forms with the following setting;

```
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {
    'change_password': 'apps.accounts.forms.ChangePasswordForm',
    'reset_password': 'apps.accounts.forms.ResetPasswordForm',
    'signup': 'apps.accounts.forms.SignupForm',
}
```

If you pass a `pid` to the form, you can then make it an attribute of the form instance in the `__init__` and assign it to the profile during the save. Or have `pid` as a field, pass it a value in the initial data for the form and have it as a hidden input (`forms.HiddenInput()` is the widget).

Then in the `clean_pid()` you could validate that the value is unique against the other rows in the table. Depending on what you're doing with this data, it'd make most sense to use something like a UUID so that you don't have to worry so much about clashing values.

Comment: Hi @markwalker_ thanks for the tips. Any idea how i can use the pid field input of the form to filter the User.objects? self.fields["pid"] does not work for med unfurtunatly!

`data = User.objects.filter(profile__pid=self.fields["pid"]) 
if data.exists(): msg = "This pid already exists" 
self.add_error('pid', msg)`

Comment: You can filter with the form data like I showed in your other question here; https://stackoverflow.com/a/68082131/1199464