# forms validationerror sends me to a ValidationerError page

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Ive been struggling with this problem for days now. As you se the validation error works but i want the error to show in the form and not redirect the user to the ValidationError page. What am i missing? I use django Alluth

```
def custom_signup(self, request, user):
    user.profile.pid = self.cleaned_data[_("pid")]
    data = User.objects.filter(profile__pid=user.profile.pid)
    if data.exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            _('This user exists in our system. Please try another.'),
            code='unique_pid'
        )
    else:
        user.save()
        return user
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so first you need to create a custom signup form, I've detailed how that is done in [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68081727/1199464)

What you're seeing there is a 500 page, in debug mode (so you get all the information about what's happened). The reason that you're seeing this is that you are raising an error.

What you want to do, is to add an error to a form as part of that form's validation.

Once you've created your custom signup form, you can add your validation as part of the form's `clean` method;

```py
    def clean(self):
        """
        Clean the form
        """
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        pid = self.cleaned_data["pid"]

        if User.objects.filter(profile__pid=pid).exists():
            self.add_error(
                'pid',
                _('This user exists in our system. Please try another.'),
            )

        return cleaned_data
```

Please note, you're also using translation (`_("")`) to access the form's `cleaned_data` - you don't need to do this.

Comment: thank you for taking your time to help. You are a genius it works.